# Views: Display block based on taxonomy term

Tags: views

I have a vocabulary (Alive or Deceased) that has 2 terms (alive and deceased).
If the node is under "alive" category there should be displayed block A, otherwise no block should be displayed.

How can I do that using views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you edit your view, there is a section called "Filter Criteria" in the left column (Drupal 7 / Views 3). Click on "Add" in the Filter section, then limit the criteria to Taxonomy only by choosing "Taxonomy Term" in the Filter drop-down. You should see the correct category, then just pick the term you want to check for ("alive").